# How to set my user info globally once authenticated

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication, ssrs-2008-r2

I have successfully implemented Windows Authentication in my Intranet ASP.NET Core 1.0 Web App and the user name is available through `User.Identity.Name` in my controller in the form of `DOMAIN\user`. I am also using Entity Framework Core.

What I would like to do is to get extra user info that I have from my SQL Server database for this `DOMAIN\user` and have this stored in a global way.  I could set and check a cookie value through `HttpContext.Session` on every controller action but I would prefer a global method. How could I go about doing this?

Comment: you didn't mention about the nature or size of the user data you want to make available, but for small data items about the user you could add custom claims either by implementing a custom claimsprincipalfactory or using claims transformations. then you can easily check the claims of the current user

Comment: I will most likely return a single row value

Comment: I am able to add a claim to the claim principal but the data does not persist. I am going to wait until RC2 as Windows Authentication is not fully integrated yet it seems. [Github Issue 1232](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1232)

Answer (score 1):

We're doing this by "enriching" the logged in user with additional information on each request using [claims](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html?highlight=claims) and [middleware](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html). For the record, we're using cookie authentication, but I don't think it matters.

Here's our approach:

1. Create a [middleware](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) class which will serve as the entrypoint for fetching non-persisted [claims](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html?highlight=claims), i.e. claims we're not interested in storing in our cookie, and in your case claims which aren't automatically initialized via Windows Authentication.
2. Let the [middleware](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) grab some additional information and add it to the current user based on the users ID.
   In the example below we're using a variety of `IMyClaimProvider`s to fetch additional [claims](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html?highlight=claims) for the current user.

   ```
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Security.Claims;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
   using Microsoft.AspNet.Http;

   class UserClaimsMiddleware
   {
       private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

       public UserClaimsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
       {
           _next = next;
       }

       public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IEnumerable<IMyClaimProvider> claimProviders)
       {
           foreach (var claimProvider in claimProviders)
           {
               var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) httpContext.User.Identity;
               var identifier = identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
               var claims = claimProvider.GetNonPersistentClaims(identifier);
               identity.AddClaims(claims);
           }
           await _next(httpContext);
       }
   }
   ```
3. How you decide to fetch additional information is very much up to you. 
   In our case the `System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier` is simply a GUID identifiyng a row in a database, and this row holds basic information like first name, last name, address and email, which we're returning as a collection of claims.

   ```
   interface IMyClaimProvider
   {
       IEnumerable<Claim> GetNonPersistentClaims(string nameIdentifier);
   }
   ```
4. Register the middleware on application startup. **The order of middleware is important!** 
   Our custom middleware must be registered *after* the middleware used for authentication.

   ```
   public void Configure(IHostingEnvironment environment, IApplicationBuilder application, ILoggerFactory loggerfactory)
   {
       application.UseIISPlatformHandler();
       application.UseStaticFiles();
       [...]
       application.UseMiddleware<UserClaimsMiddleware>();
       [...]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried [@Uli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1764844/uli)'s answer but the 2nd part of [this post](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) helped me get the user's full name back from the claim.